# Magento 1.9 - How to post data from predispatch event to controller action

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I want to change the data that is processed in the `checkout_onepage_saveBilling` controller action.

I am using an observer with the predispatch event to catch the POST data which is coming from the address form in the checkout and manipulate the values.

How can I transfer this data to the controller action now?

This is my observer:

```
public function validateAddress($observer)
{

    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $action = $controller->getFullActionName();

    if ($action == "checkout_onepage_saveBilling") {
        $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
        $post[billing][postcode] = trim($post[billing][postcode]);
        $post[billing][city] = trim($post[billing][city]);
    }

}
```

Comment: U need to use a plugin beforeExecute in this action

Comment: So I cannot use the predispatch event for that?
How would I do that?

Comment: Sorry for that in this case you can't use the plugin in Magento 1 you must override the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this now, using the setPost method of the request:

```
public function validateAddress($observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http $request */
        $request = $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest();
        if (!$request->isPost() || !$request->isAjax()) {
            return;
        }

        $action = $request->getActionName();
        if ($action == "saveBilling") {
            $this->_fixAddress($request, "billing");
        } elseif ($action == "saveShipping") {
            $this->_fixAddress($request, "shipping");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http $request
     * @param string                            $type
     */
    protected function _fixAddress($request, $type)
    {
        $address             = $request->getPost($type, array());
        $address["postcode"] = trim(htmlspecialchars($address["postcode"]));
        $address["city"]     = trim(htmlspecialchars($address["city"]));
        $request->setPost($type, $address);
    }
```